# Immutable.js difference between toJSON() and toObject() on Record

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

With the release of Immutable v4, there has been some api changes.

`toJS(): any` became `toJS(): {[key: string]: unknown}`

From what I understand it has been replaced by `toJSON()` but what's the difference with `toObject()` ? The [documentation](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/Record/#toObject()) isn't very clear on that topic.

```
toJSON(): TProps
   Shallowly converts this Record to equivalent native JavaScript Object.

toObject(): TProps
   Shallowly converts this Record to equivalent JavaScript Object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names can be taken literally:

`toObject` creates javascript plain *objects*, while `toJSON` chooses the datatype based on the collection type.

For *keyed* collections (Record, Map, OrderedMap), toJSON and toObject do the same.

However, for list types (Lists, Set, OrderedSet) there is a difference:
`toJSON` returns an Array, while `toObject` generates an Object where the keys are the indexes:

```
List(['a','b']).toJSON()   // ['a', 'b']
List(['a','b']).toObject() // { "1": "a", "2": "b" }
```